# Application builded by electron-builder problems with openssl

Tags: openssl, electron, electron-builder

I got the problem with electron application that uses openssl library. Application is builded by electron-builder (version 19.55.2). 
Application works using `npm start command`. Unfortunately, builded one returns the following:
`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bypass that problem as follows:

1. Install `openssl` library and extract `libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` to your project.
2. Include `sudo-prompt` library in your project (it allows to generate sudo commands inside node application or invoke `.sh` scripts using administrator privileges)
3. Create `.sh` script that checks whether `libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` file resides in the `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/` directory, if not - copy that file to the new directory (`mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/ && cp ./libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib $_)`